# UIBarButtonItem stays highlighted when using popViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am having an issue with `UINavigationController popViewController:` method: when I go from **controller A** to **controller B** using a navigation controller button and then pop the **controller B**, the navigation controller button (in **controller A**) stays highlighted for about 20 seconds.

On the other hand, if I go from **B** to **A** using the actual back button, the nav button appears in its normal state (not highlighted).

Any Ideas?

### States List:

State 1: **Controller A**:
State 2: **Controller B**:
State 3.1: **Controller A** using popViewController:
State 3.2: **Controller A** using backButton:

### States Images:

State 1: **Controller A**:
[image: State 1]

State 2: **Controller B**:
[image: State 2]

State 3.1: **Controller A** using popViewController:
[image: State 3.1]

State 3.2: **Controller A** using backButton:
[image: State 3.2]

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: Sorry, It's been some time now @IgorKulman